# Whom is Paul talking to in Philippians 2:14?

Tags: philippians

Philippians 2:14
Do everything without grumbling or arguing,

Was Pauling addressing only the Philippians? To all the churches then? And now?

Comment: Is there a reason you think such a generic instruction *wouldn't* apply to more than just the church at Philippi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance, when writing to the Christians at Philippi around 61 A.D., they were the ones being instructed to do everything without grumbling or arguing. He even names two  individuals, Euodoas and Syntyche, who were not of the same mind in the Lord (4:2). They were part of the congregation at Philippi as 4:15 makes clear:- "Now ye Philippians know also..."

In his letter to the Christians at Colossae, he concludes it by instructing them to pass that letter on to the congregation of believers in Laodicea and then to those in Hierapolis (4:13). But there is no such instruction with this letter to the Philippians.

Of course, we know with hindsight that this letter was preserved and kept along with all the other epistles and gospel accounts of the first century. If it had not, nobody in later centuries would have had copies of it. But it was still in the possession of the early church in the second century and following. It became common knowledge within the church and valued as equally inspired of the Holy Spirit as the rest. Its doctrinal content is so sublime, showing the humility of Christ, then his glorification (chapter two) it ranks as of great value to all Christians, at all times, in all places. And the practical instructions about not arguing or grumbling also apply to all Christians, at all times, in all places.

Answer (score 1):

#### Whom is Paul talking to in Philippians 2:14?

This verse is part of the letter that Paul wrote "To all God's holy people in Christ Jesus at Philippi" (Phil. 1:1) [NIV]. As an "apostle to the Gentiles" (Rom. 11:13), Paul earnestly worked at helping those who had recently come to know Christ to change their former ways to be in line with what it meant to be a Christian.

For Christians throughout the centuries, we strive to do what is right in God's eyes and wage war with the imperfect flesh (Rom. 7:14-25). God has given us all his holy writings to help us just as Paul mentions:

> "All Scripture is inspired of God and beneficial for teaching, for reproving, for setting things straight, for disciplining in righteousness,  17 so that the man of God may be fully competent, completely equipped for every good work."–2 Tim. 3:16, 17 (NWT)